# Conditional and joint distribution of the sum of exponential RVs

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution, exponential-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. $Exp(\lambda)$ random variables and $Y_k =\sum^{k}_{i=1}X_i$, $k = 1,2,...,n$.

a) Find the joint PDF of $Y_1,...,Y_n$.

b) Find the conditional PDF of $Y_k$ conditioned on $Y_1,....,Y_{k−1}$, for $k = 2,3,...,n$.

c) Show that $Y_1,...,Y_k$ conditioned on $Y_{k+1},...,Y_n$ is uniformly distributed over a subset in $\Bbb{R}^k$, for $k = 1,2,...,n−1$. Find this subset.

My attempt:

By change of variable I got:
$$f_{Y_1
,...,
Y_
n}
(
y_
1
,...,
y_
n
)=λexp(−λ
y_
n
)$$

for the b) using: 
$$f_{
Y_
k
|
Y_
1
,...,
Y_{
k−1}}
(
y_
k
|
y_
1
,...,
y_{
k−1}
)=
\frac{
f_{
Y_
1
,..,
Y_
k}
(
y_
1
,...,
y_
k
)}{
f_{
Y_
k}
(
y_
k
)}$$
I got: 
$$f_{
Y_
k
|
Y_
1
,...,
Y_{
k−1}}
(
y_
k
|
y_
1
,...,
y_{
k−1}
)=(k−1)!(λ
y_
k)^{
1−k}$$

and for c) using 
$$f_{
Y_
1
,..,
Y_
k
|
Y_{
k+1}
,...,
Y_
n}
(
y_
1
,...,
y_
k
|
y_{
k+1}
,...,
y_
n
)=\frac{
f_{
Y_
1
,..,
Y_
n}
(
y_
1
,...,
y_
n
)}{
f_{
Y_
1
,...,
Y_
k}
(
y_
1
,...,
y_{
k
−1})}$$

I got 
$$\frac{1}{
exp(λ(
y_
n
−
y_
k
))}
$$

Now I am stuck on how to show that it is uniformly distributed and to find the subset because I don't think that my answer looks like a uniformly distributed PDF...

Comment: The subset when $Y_{k+1}=y_{k+1}$ is all points $(z_1,z_2,\ldots,z_k) \in \mathbb R^n$ where  $0 \le z_1\le z_2 \le \ldots \le z_k \le y_{k+1}$

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3683117/321264.